# Equivalent of QEvent ApplicationDeactivate

Tags: qt, qevent

I use the events `QEvent::ApplicationActivate` and `QEvent::ApplicationDeactivate` to show/hide some part of my app when needed.

But now, thoses events are flagged as *deprecated* :

> This enum has been deprecated. Use ApplicationStateChange instead.

So I tried to switch to this event. It is triggered when it should, but I can't find a way to get the application state with some sort of cast or any getters.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just as for any other event, you need to cast it to more specific type to get event properties. The class is `QApplicationStateChangeEvent`. The documentation is surprisingly silent about it, but it exists and is declared in `event.h`. The following code works fine in my Qt 5.1 installation:

```
#include <QApplicationStateChangeEvent>

bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *o, QEvent *e) {
  if (e->type() == QEvent::ApplicationStateChange) {
    qDebug() << "state:" 
             << static_cast<QApplicationStateChangeEvent*>(e)->applicationState();
  }
  return QMainWindow::eventFilter(o, e);
}
```

Comment: @MartinDelille WindowDeactivate is depreciated but maintained for backwards compatibility. It is only there to keep old Qt programs working, but isn't recommended for use.